# Como hacer binding en diferentes textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]mi problema es sencillo, tengo 13 textbox y diferentes botones del 0 al 9 como una calculadora. Lo q quiero hacer es q cuando presione un textbox y luego empiece a presionar los botones, se muestre en ese textbox los valores de los botones, pero no quiero q se muestre en el resto de textbox, pero el resto de los textbox tmb tienen q estar bindeados a esos botones para poder realizar la misma operación. Como lo logro, estoy usando el patrón MVVM??

```
En mi ViewModel:
public class ATMRegisterViewModel : ObservableCollectionPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
 private string _resultado;

        public string Resultado
        {
            get { return _resultado; }
            set
            {
                _resultado = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Resultado");
            }
        }
  public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }

private void MainButtonClick(object sender)
        {
            Resultado += sender.ToString();


        }
public ATMRegisterViewModel()
        {
 ButtonCommand = new RelayComand(o => MainButtonClick(o.ToString()));

}

}

Mi View:
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Resultado}" Name="uno" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Cantidad" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15" Foreground="#424242"/>

  <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="2"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="2"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="3"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="4"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="4"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="5"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="5"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="6"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="6"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="7"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="7"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="8"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="8"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="9"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="9"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="0"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="0"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="00"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="00"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content=","
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter=","/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="*"
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="*"/>
                            <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Content="&#8998;" 
                    Style="{StaticResource KeyboardBtnTheme}">
                                <Button.LayoutTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" Angle="180"/>
                                </Button.LayoutTransform>
                            </Button>
    introducir el código aquí

Puse solo un textbox y la caja de botones
```

Comment: Vas a hacer una calculadora?

Comment: no, la caja de botones del 0-9 es como la de las calculadoras pero no es para eso...es mas bien para una caja registradora, donde tengo varias denominaciones de billetes y desde la caja de botones debo llenar los textbox correspondiente a la denominación de bilete

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el codigo que has intentado. Por otra parte pq tienes q usar 13 textbox, no te basta con uno?

Comment: No jefe, pq son 13 denominaciones de billetes y se necesita saber q cantidad de billetes de cada tipo hay en la caja

Comment: Ok, ya entiendo, ahora es importante que edites tu pregunta y añadas el código q has intentado

Comment: Pero ya hiciste el binding para resultado.. no termino de entender tu pregunta... cualquier otro textbox es igual....

Comment: lo q pasa es q cuando toco la caja de botones....como la propiedad text esta bindeada a resltado...en las cjas de textos se muestra el mismo resultado....si toco 123...en todos los textbox me sale 123....

Comment: y lo q kiero es, q cuando toque el primer textbox y luego empiece a tocar los botones, q el contenido solo se muestre en ese textbox, cuando toque el segundo textbox lo mismo....y así sucesivamente